# Div inside display:table-row section not expanding to full width

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm trying to set a layout for my website using table displays for my html tags.

Although most of them work the way I want, I can't figure out how to get my display:block div to fully expand inside a display:table-cell section that succsessfully spans all the columns...

When I run the inspector, I can see that all my html tags are fine (like tables, rows and cells) but the  inside the section tag.

Any tips ? Here's my code :

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  display: table-row;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
}

header > div {
  display: table-cell;
}

section {
  display: table-row;
  background-color: #DDDDDD;
  column-span: all;
  -webkit-column-span: all; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
}

section > div {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

footer {
  display: table-row;
  column-span: all;
  -webkit-column-span: all; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
}

.h-sep {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.v-sep {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.tile-s-fixed {
  width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<header>

  <div class="h-sep v-sep">One</div>

  <div class="tile-s-fixed h-sep">Two</div>

</header>

<section>

  <div class="h-sep">Three</div>

</section>

<footer>

  <div>Four</div>

</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to make some changes to your approach and go with something closer to this:
http://jsfiddle.net/ZQQY4/

You'll need to utilize

```
display: table-row-group AND display: table-caption;
```

Comment: Will this work if I use my full span cell as a container for more divs ?

Comment: Yes anything that is inside the div with display: table-caption; should take up the full amount of space in the table row.